# Using external HSQLDB instead of in process

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

Messing around with HSQLDB, downloaded the latest and set that up in a different directory from project. Can see it in the DB manager and can create tables and do some CRUD. However, I can't seem to use the correct database in a spring project.

Config datasource line:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql//localhost/exploring;shutdown=true;"/>
```

The app will create a 'exploring' database inside the project with the structure from the url property:

```
-hsql
    -localhost
        -exploring files (.script, .properties, etc.)
```

Any operations will use the in project database and never the one set up in the other directory. How do I use the first database I created?

I have tried pointing to a specific port but it does not pick it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the URL, you need a colon after “hsql”:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/exploring;shutdown=true;"/>
                                            ^
```

And of course, you need to have started a server. Either [from the application](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/listeners-chapt.html#lsc_app_start) or a [standalone one](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_server_modes).